# How to deploy React build folder to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I looked around the internet for this and found [this medium article](https://medium.com/quick-code/deploying-production-build-of-react-app-to-heroku-2548d8bf6936) using serve. The article directed modifying the packange.json file to this:

```
"scripts": { 
  "dev": "react-scripts 
  "start", "start": "serve -s build", 
  "build": "react-scripts build", 
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject", 
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build" 
},
```

Now this works in development. I get console logs saying Content is cached for offline use. And google Lighthouse gives me >90% on progessive web apps. The problem is, when I deploy to Heroku, during build it runs the npm run build specified in the package.json scripts. But on opening the app, I get 21% on performance, and 50% on progressive web apps in firehouse. Also, it says service worker not registered. Which means it is not serving from the build folder. As an extra, I ran npm build myself in development machine and deployed the project TOGETHER with the build folder, but still same result. Now I also came around [this other article](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08)suggesting to use node.js server and change scripts in package.json to this:

```
start: "node server.js"
```

I no nothing about node.js, so I decided to consult here for better choices.

EDIT: If a server command is needed, like in the node.js in the second medium article, and in Garesh's php code below - if anyone could help with a similar code in python(django), it'd be nice

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer to this in this comment online:

Before deploying the app go to:
Heroku dashboard > settings > buildpacks > add buildpacks and then add github.com/mars/create-react-app-b...

Or, in command line you can do

heroku buildpacks:set github.com/mars/create-react-app-b...

If you don't do this step, heroku will deploy the development build (which is slow) of your react app instead of the optimized production build.

Answer (score 0):

Build you code with:

`npm run build`

Now Put this code in the `index.php` file:

```
<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>
```

Now put this `index.php` file into your build folder.

Copy this build folder somewhere else.

Now configure your new folder with your heroku app.

then

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hey Harish, first, I deploy my heroku app from my connected github account repo, so in essence I should push ONLY the build folder, maybe to a different branch on github, and then deploy heroku from there? Second, do you know how I could replace the php file and lines with that of Python (pref Django).